# <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging> pom error

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml, war

I'm getting this error in my pom.xml

> Project build error: Unknown packaging: ${packaging.type}

I'm looking for solutions but I'm not finding anything that solves it. This is my pom.xml (shorted). Any ideas?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.telefonica.npro</groupId>
<artifactId>NProWebApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

<name>NProWeb</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jar</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>war</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            <spring.profiles.active>ds</spring.profiles.active>
            <log4j2.config>log4j2-cert.xml</log4j2.config>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: You either need to make any of the profile active by setting `activeByDefault` to true or add a default property similar to `java.version`

Comment: Please, could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Make a decision what kind of packaging you like to have either jar or war? Furthermore I strongly recommend to use a more recent version of spring boot cause 1.X line is end of life.. Furthermore you should not mix spring-boot profiles with Maven profiles. The question is: What kind of problem you are trying to solve to define the packaging via a property?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the packaging.type variable inside the pom that will use it as the value won't have been defined at the time Maven needs to resolve it. One way around this would be to use a packaging type of "pom". The downside to this is that you will have to include the packaging type on the layout parameter of the spring boot maven plugin.

Note: I have not tried this myself.